# AngularJS : conditional wrap in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, conditional-statements, wrapper

I'm trying to wrap an element in an ng-repeat loop if the item has specific values.

eg:

```
items={
  {name:"AAA",cat:"1"},
  {name:"BBB",cat:"2"},
  {name:"CCC",cat:"1"},
  {name:"DDD",cat:"3"}
}
...
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  {{item.name}}
</div>
```

will output:

```
<div>AAA</div>
<div>BBB</div>
<div>CCC</div>
<div>DDD</div>
```

Let's say I want to wrap items that have category=1.
required output:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>AAA</div>
</div>
<div>BBB</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>CCC</div>
</div>
<div>DDD</div>
```

Note that I already have a filter and an orderBy in my ng-repeat, so can't use that.
Any advice how to achieve that?

Many thanks

Edit: I can't use a class, I need a wrapper div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done just by using `ng-class` as follows-

```js
function MainCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.items=[
  {name:"AAA",cat:"1"},
  {name:"BBB",cat:"2"},
  {name:"CCC",cat:"1"},
  {name:"DDD",cat:"3"}
]
 
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color : #ccc;  
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main"> 
  <ul>
     <div ng-repeat="item in items">
  
    <div class="wrapper" ng-if="item.cat ==  1">
      {{item.name}}
    </div>
    <div ng-if="item.cat !=  1">
     {{item.name}}
  </div>  
  </ul>
</div>
```

**EDITS**:

According to your edited Question this is best of my knowledge. Its implemented in above snippet.

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in items">

        <div class="wrapper" ng-if="item.cat ==  1">
          {{item.name}}
        </div>
        <div ng-if="item.cat !=  1">
         {{item.name}}
      </div>
```

Note: if you dont want to use `Class` it can be done using `id`

Comment: Thanks, but that means I have to repeat twice the actual content. Here we have a simple {{item.name}} but in reality I have much more...

Comment: As far as its in single loop, I don't think it will cause any problem.. still there's always some space for uncertainty so you need to follow _try and error_ method.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'wrapper' : item.category == 1}">
  {{item.name}}
</div>
```

You don't need an extra div

Comment: I edited my question, I can't use a class, I need a wrapper div.